# setUserVisibleHint() issue with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentstatepageradapter

I know this question has already been asked on different website (such as [here](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2014/02/20/a-bug-in-and-a-fix-for-the-way-fragmentstatepageradapter-handles-fragment-restoration/) and [there](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid/issues/34) for example, but I struggle to find a solution to my specific use case. 
 
Here is the thing: I have 3 tabs (each tabs extends `Fragment`) which are hosted by an `ActionBarActivity` (called *Home*). *Home* holds a `ViewPager` which extends a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (this is where the differents tabs are created).

When I swipe to the last tabs (the 3rd one), I use `setUserVisibleHint()` to load some data from server using `AsyncTask<>`:

```
public class TabOperations extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisible())
            loadUserRequestByDate(); // Launch Asynctask<> method.
    }
}
```

It works well when a swipe from first tab to the last one. But, When I swipe back to the tab before (so, the 2nd one), the method in `setUserVisibleHint()` (so, `loadUserRequestByDate()`) is triggered.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried retaining the fragments with setOffscreenPageLimit(3) for your viewpager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: If you keep an offscreenpagelimit of 3 for the viewpager, all the 3 fragments will be kept alive even when you keep switching between them. This should avoid calling all the fragment lifecycle methods again and again.

Comment: Loading data in setUserVisibleHint() may not be prescribed in this case. Can you try loading via viewPageChangeListener

Comment: I see the point. Just tried it, but does not work unfortunately. I can't use viewPageChangeListener due to my code configuration.

Comment: If you are that particular about loading via setUserVisibleHint() , then keep a boolean variable to indicate if data was loaded once, to prevent subsequent loading while switching tabs.

But, the ideal approach would be to make use of setOffscreenPageLimit.